# jQuery scrollable ul via arrow ( and remove arrow when reached top or bottom end of list )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

see http://liveweave.com/Pieivc

what i want that in start there show be no icon for arrow up as not needed but when user click arrow down it appears should appears and when user reaches last itme in ul li list bottom arrow should vanish

how can i do to check it ?..

```
(function () {

  $('#scrollup').on({
    'mousedown touchstart': function() {
      $(".sidebar-menu").animate({scrollTop:  0}, 2000);
    },
    'mouseup touchend': function() {
      $(".sidebar-menu").stop(true);
    }
  });

  $('#scrolldown').on({
    'mousedown touchstart': function() {
      $(".sidebar-menu").animate({
        scrollTop:  $(".sidebar-menu")[0].scrollHeight
      }, 2000);
    },
    'mouseup touchend': function() {
      $(".sidebar-menu").stop(true);
    }
});

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this using `$('.sidebar-menu').scrollTop()` value.

So for example, I wrote a function called check(), which checks the location of the scroll and display/hide the appropriate arrows. This function is called on mouse touchend event of each arrow.

```
function check() {
    if ($('.sidebar-menu').scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('#scrollup').hide();
        $('#scrolldown').show();
    } else if ($('.sidebar-menu').scrollTop() == height - 100) {
        $('#scrolldown').hide();
        $('#scrollup').show();
    }
}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ry2zwho1/1/

Comment: works fine but is show only one arraow suppose it user scoll down and has to got 2 content up this will not work

Comment: You are right. I fixed the check function http://jsfiddle.net/ry2zwho1/2/ i feel like this could be done better but cant think of a way now

Comment: one qsn why did u write $('.sidebar-menu').scrollTop() == height - 100, instead of hardcoded 100 can we use something else

Comment: Because the scrolltop() value does not take into account the height of the container itself, so we need to offset that to determine when we have hit bottom of page. So for example the TOTAL container length is 300, and you have set the container to be 100px height. Then the scrolltop() value at the bottom of the page is 300-100 = 200

Comment: You can also get the height of the container dynamically by using jquery $('.sidebar-menu').height(), which will return 100 or whatever the height if container is. You are thinking correctly! :) great job

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGLsG/95/)

```
$(function(){
var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
var clickCount = 0;
var canClick = true;
$(".btnPrevious").css('color', 'red').show();
itemWidth =......
```